# Compiling counts of records by month and user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a dashboard I'm working on that basically lists all the users of the system and the number of activities they have in each month. I'm curious on what others think would be an efficient way to compile this data. I'm thinking I should eventually attempt to get it in this format:

{
  user1 => { :jan => 13, :feb => 21, :mar => 4, ... },
  user2 => { :jan => 16, :feb => 18.... },
  ....
}

Though I'm by no means married to that idea. Here is screenshot of what I'm working towards to help give you a better idea:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbSln.png

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an activity log to track activity (one record per activity), then it should be pretty simple. Basically, COUNT(*) your activity records per user, and GROUP them by the month in which they occurred.

Alternatively, and depending on your requirements, you could also just have a single record per user, per month (instead of a log), with an incrementing count of the number of activities.